# UITableViewCell Percentage Based Height with Minimum Height

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, xcode6

I have a custom tableview cell where I'm letting auto layout manage the height for it.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44 
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Inside the TableViewCell I have a subview:

```
contentView.addSubview(subView)
```

I'd like the TableViewCell to be either 40% of the screen's height or 250pts.

I've gotten it to work by doing this:

```
self.contentView.autoSetDimension(.Height, toSize: round(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height * 0.40), relation: .GreaterThanOrEqual)
self.contentView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Leading)
self.contentView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Trailing)
self.subView.autoSetDimension(.Height, toSize: 250, relation: .GreaterThanOrEqual)

subView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Top)
subView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Leading)
subView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Trailing)
subView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Bottom)
```

This looks kind of sloppy to me. Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use UITableViewAutomaticDimension when you want to have a constant height for cells?

Comment: It's because the other cells in the table view have dynamic heights

Comment: I would implement heightForRowAtIndexPath and return 40% of the screen's height or 250pts where you can and only UITableViewAutomaticDimension when you need it, this will greatly improve performance when scrolling

Comment: Hmm, so it's possible to use auto resizing cells and still use heightForRowAtIndexPath? This cell doesn't auto resize, but other cells in my tableView do based off the amount of content

Comment: Yep if you return UITableViewAutomaticDimension in heightForRow it says "this specific indexPath is self-sizing".....(as long as estmatedHeight is also set which you have done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add constraints to the `contentView` that will auto fitting its size to the `subView`, try this:

```
subView.autoSetDimension(.Height, toSize: round(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height * 0.40), relation: .GreaterThanOrEqual)
subView.autoSetDimension(.Height, toSize: 250, relation: .GreaterThanOrEqual)

subView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero)
```